# How do you adjust the trace rotation on a Hameg HM 307?

Tags: oscilloscope, trace

I have a [rather old] Hameg HM 307 oscilloscope with the trace rotation slightly off. There is no trace rotation adjuster anywhere on the outside of the device. The user manual mentions that it is possible to adjust the trace rotation but it doesn't say how to do it.

Does anybody know how this is

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any means of electrically adjusting the rotation from a brief look through the [pdf manual](http://www.hameg.com/downloads/man/HM307_english.pdf).

However, you might be able to adjust the yoke or even physically rotate the CRT in it's mountings - just watch-out for EHT voltages!!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I was hoping to be able to adjust it without having to physically move the CRT.

Comment: Little chance there is a yoke in an oscilloscope. They are usualy driven by applying an electric field to plates, not by a magnetic field as in a TV receiver. Also, before opening the device, take a careful look if the grid isn't integrated in the CRT itself.

Comment: I think that the grid is separate, I read somewhere (probably in the manual) that if the CRT rotates [maybe during transit] then it can cause the trace to be rotated. Also the grid casts a shadow behind itself (presumably on to the actual screen). I might try to the move the CRT in that case.

Comment: @jippie - Hah! You're right about the yoke. I wasn't thinking. The manual has a schematic and an internal layout showing internal adjustments - no sign of trace-rotate. Of course it might be possible to rotate the graticule as a last resort :)

Answer (score 0):

I've got one of those with the same problem. (I used it only yesterday...)

It might be possible to fix it but it won't be an electrical adjustment where you just open the case and turn a potentiometer. It probably involves physically rotating the tube inside the case, or there might be some adjustment magnets around the base of the CRT tube.

I say: Leave it alone. Rejoice in it!